# How to add TextShape to a document with Python Uno

Tags: python, document, libreoffice, pyuno

After connecting to a document I have this code:

```
page = document.getDrawPages().getByIndex( 0 )

textshape = document.createInstance('com.sun.star.drawing.TextShape')
textshape.setSize(Size(150, 150))
textshape.setPosition(Point(100, 100))
textshape.setString('Test') 
textshape.CharColor = 0
textshape.CharHeight = 12

page.add(textshape)
```

The code does not give an error, but nothing happens.

What is the proper way to add a TextShape to a document with Python?